# Changing Spritefont Sizes Without Anti-Aliasing in MonoGame

Tags: monogame, spritefont

I'm using a custom font for a small game in MonoGame, and it is made on an 8x8 grid, so I have to scale it to make it bigger. Currently I am scaling the scale in the spriteBatch.Begin() method, but this means I have to call the End() and Begin() method for every font size I want, which is very inefficient. I found a solution online to prevent anti-aliasing for the Begin() method, but what I want to know is: is there a way to prevent anti-aliasing when scaling by changing the XML file of the spritefont? Any help would be appreciated! :D